# Is there a way to find connections in a matrix?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to code a function, which will show
these examples.

a. connection (False)
node 1 is connected to node 2

b. shared connection(True)
node 1 is connected to node 2 while node 2 is connected to node 3
therefore meaning node 1 and node 3 shares a connection with node 2

c. disconnection(False)
node 1 and node 4 are completely disconnected

it needs to return a boolean value like for example

```
matrix = [[ [0,1,1,1,0],
             [1,0,0,1,0],
             [1,0,0,0,1],
             [1,1,0,0,0],
             [0,0,1,0,0] ]
```

calling nodeconn(matrix, 0, 4) should return true as the matrix shows a connection shared between node 0 and node 4, both being connected to node 2.

also calling nodeconn(matrix, 1, 4) should return False as 1 and 4 have no nodes in common

I have Tried converting the matrix to an edgelist and using a for loop to loop through. It didnt work so i changed my approach

```
def nodeconn(matrix, node1, node2):
    n1 = matrix[node1]
    n2 = graph_matrix[node2]
    for index in matrix:
        for connections in index:
            if connections in n1 and n2:
                return True
            elif nd1[node2]==1:
                return False
    return False
```

Comment: The main Problem now is it returns True always even when there is a clear disconnection

Comment: You could use: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csgraph.shortest_path.html#scipy.sparse.csgraph.shortest_path

Comment: what do you want to return if 2 nodes has shared connection but over 2+ nodes?

Comment: @ingvar if 2 nodes share like 2+ connections it should return true as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find shared connection with > 1 node in path you can use bfs:

```
def check_if_path_exists(matrix, node1, node2):
    queue = [node1]
    visited = set()
    while queue:
        current_node = queue.pop(0)
        visited.add(current_node)

        for index, is_connected in enumerate(matrix[current_node]):
            if not is_connected:
                continue

            if index == node2:
                return True
            elif index not in visited and index not in queue:
                queue.append(index)

    return False

def check_if_connection_is_shared(matrix, node1, node2):
    if matrix[node1][node2]:
        return False  # connected

    return check_if_path_exists(matrix, node1, node2)
```

If you want to find nodes with only 1 node in shared connection this code can be simplified:

```
def check_if_connection_is_shared(matrix, node1, node2):
    if matrix[node1][node2]:
        return False  # connected directly

    for a, b in zip(matrix[node1], matrix[node2]):  # if both node1 and node2 are connected to the same node, in connections list element with this node number will be 1 for both node1 and node2.
        if a and b:
            return True

    return False
```